# Source user defined functions in R

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I have created a script with a few custom functions and have saved the file in one of the folders.

However, if i want to access the functions using `source("Functions.R")` i have to have the "Functions.R" file in my working directory. Is there any way of fetching the file without copying it to my current working directory? (I do not want to create a package for it)

Thanks!

Comment: `file` parameter can be a path

Comment: @Clemsang Okay, thanks. Will try it out